# How do I change the width of select2 tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to put a select2 tag inside my XHTML. However, I can't control its width. I have tried a lot of stuff, but none of them work.

Here is the problem I am currently facing:

[image: Here is the problem]

I even tried to put CSS for select2 and then keep `width:600px`. But it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Health Condition</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us more about you</h3>
    <input type="text" class="medicalCondition" name="medicalCondition placeholder="What condition are you facing?" />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block">
            <select type="text" id="mealPreferences" multiple="true">
                <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
                <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
                <option value="Pork">Pork</option>
                <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my attempt in CSS:

```
.container {

}

.block {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mealPreferences {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mealPreferences` is an **id not class**. **So you are using a wrong css method** to define the rules. **Use** `#mealPreferences` **not** `.mealPreferences` **to define the css rule.**

> Change Css From-

```
.mealPreferences {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

> To-

```
#mealPreferences {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

> Below is the working example-

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#mealPreferences {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <select type="text" id="mealPreferences" multiple="true">
                        <option value="Beef">Beef</option>
                        <option value="Chicken">Chicken</option>
                        <option value="Pork">Pork</option>
                        <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
                    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: width still didnt change

Answer (score 0):

In CSS if you define the classes (use `.` before name), to define any id you need to use `#`, use this:

```
.container {

}

.block {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#mealPreferences {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: width still didnt change

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the object `width: 100%` and `max-width: (maximum px you want)` on css

Comment: width still didnt change